# Google Apis explorer is not working in local development server

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-python

Google Apis explorer is not working in local development server and it is showing no error just a redirect.

> INFO     2016-02-01 06:19:42,645 module.py:787] default: "GET
>   /_ah/api/explorer HTTP/1.1" 302 - INFO     2016-02-01 06:19:45,206
>   module.py:787] default: "GET
>   /*ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F*%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.mX-Sl4wQAT8.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNc6PXZbysb_U3xKZFWCKbDMDUETg
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 7933 INFO     2016-02-01 06:19:52,044 module.py:787]
>   default: "GET
>   /*ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F*%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.mX-Sl4wQAT8.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNc6PXZbysb_U3xKZFWCKbDMDUETg
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 7933

Im able to view discovery doc for my app also without error. I can make calls from javascript client to my apis but cannot see them on apis explorer. I was able to see them last day and in the morning gone.

- The problem persists in all apps running in the development server.
- Specs :-

  - 1.9.31 - sdk version
  - python - language
  - mac-os x

  I'm new to google cloud endpoints and I can't understand how to trace the issue. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

### Update : Workaround

The issue is unfortunately related to the latest release of Chrome. You probably need to launch a new testing Chrome profile with arguments `--user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080` as suggested by google https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=12713

To create a new chrome profile on mac-osx follow this link : 
https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

Comment: This is happening to me from today also. You may want to consider adding more information to your question to get more attention and avoid down-votes

Comment: Are you using Chrome as your browser? Try using Firefox and see if that works

Comment: We're working on documenting the workaround. You probably need to launch a new testing Chrome profile with arguments `--user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080`

Comment: @saiyr Thanks , I have updated the question with the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick as google has also changed the documentation and red banner message:

The issue is unfortunately related to the latest release of Chrome. You probably need to launch a new testing Chrome profile with arguments --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080 as suggested by google https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=12713

To create a new chrome profile on mac-osx follow this link : https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

Answer (score 3):

Something changed, and now you must start Chrome in a specific way to use api explorer on localhost development server

here is a [link](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api) to info from google.

But for me it still didn't fix using api explorer with localhost dev server.

I find that a possible workaround is to launch Chrome with the flag "--allow-running-insecure-content"
On MacOs in terminal run this:

> /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Mac/Google\ Chrome
>   --user-data-dir=test --allow-running-insecure-content

It worked for me

Comment: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue. After fiddling on the local machine, we've deployed the app and the API explorer is accessible via the remote host.

In order to access the API Explorer remotely, open the following link in your browser
https://your-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer

This is a work around till there is a solution available